# How to specify any number as a valid property key in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to store sensor data in MongoDB, say at a frequency of 1hz. To do this efficiently I want to do it the way [this article recommends](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/65517193370/schema-design-for-time-series-data-in-mongodb), namely storing multiple data points in the same document, using the number of seconds elapsed as object properties.

This is how I want a typical document to look:

```
const record = {
    startingHour: 'Sun Sep 11 2016 03:00:00', // Date object
    values: {
        0: { // minute
            0: { lat: 52.0001, lon: 13.0001 },
            // ... all other seconds
            59: { lat: 52.9999, lon: 13.9999 }
        },
        // ... all other minutes
        59: {
            0: { lat: 53.0001, lon: 14.0001 },
            // ...
            59: { lat: 53.9999, lon: 14.9999 }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I specify in Mongoose that I want each document t represent an hour with 60 properties, each key being a number from 1 to 59 - one for each minute - and each of those properties to have 60 properties in turn, and *those* records to represent the actual location values?

So to save a new record I would do `record.values.59.59 = { lat: 53.9999, lon: 14.9999 }`

How could I represent this kind of schema in Mongoose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it by creating functions to generate the objects I want. I then use those generated objects as schemas, embed one within the other and put those in the final schema:

```
/**
 * Functions to generate objects for Minutes and Seconds
 * Each object containing 60 keys, going from 0 to 59
 */
function second() {
    let obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        obj[i] = Location;
    }
    return obj;
}
function minute() {
    let obj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        obj[i] = Second;
    }
    return obj;
}

const Location = new Schema({
    latitude: { type: Number, required: true },
    longitude: { type: Number, required: true }
});

// Instantiates Second and Minute objects as schemas
const Second = new Schema(second());

const Minute = new Schema(minute());

// Actual schema
const RecordSchema = new Schema({
    startingHour: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    values: {
        type: Minute
    }
});
```

This allows me to save objects like these:

```
{
    startingHour: new Date(),
    values: {
        0: {
            0: {
                location: { latitude: 0.03, longitude: 51.7 }
            },
            1: {
                location: { latitude: 0.03, longitude: 51.7 }
            }
            // ...
        },
        // ...
        59: {
            // ...
            59: {
                location: { latitude: 0.03, longitude: 51.7 }
            }
        }
    }
}
```